# Is it possible to share value between controllers without ng-model in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to share a service value between 2 controllers, but the two-way data binding isn't working. Is it possible doing that without using `ng-model`?

```
// script.js
angular.module("MyApp")
    .factory("ValuesStore", function() {

        var service = {};

        service.visible = true;
        service.toggle = toggle;

        function toggle() {
            console.log(service.visible);
            service.visible = !service.visible;
        }

        return service;
    });

function FirstController($scope, ValuesStore) {
    $scope.visible = ValuesStore.visible;

    $scope.toggle = ValuesStore.toggle;
}

function SecondController($scope, ValuesStore) {
    $scope.visible = ValuesStore.visible;
}

<!-- template -->
<div ng-controller="FirstController">
    {{ visible }}
</div>

<div ng-controller="SecondController">
    {{ visible }}
</div>
```

All the examples I have seen use input elements with `ng-model`. Maybe I should do this using watchers or broadcast.

Comment: Where are you calling `toggle`?

Comment: I want to click a button and change the "visible" value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store `visible` variable inside some object so that it will use [**javascript prototypal inheritance**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs), value of scope will update everywhere on the view without putting watcher on the variable. Lets say we create a variable called `variables` that would have value of `visible` so that it would reflect the changes on each controller. You need to add your whole service reference to controller `scope` so that all the service variable will available on html like 
`$scope.ValuesStore = ValuesStore;`

**Markup**

```
  <div ng-controller="FirstController">
    <div ng-click="ValuesStore.toggle()">{{ ValuesStore.variables.visible }}</div>
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="SecondController">
     <div ng-click="ValuesStore.toggle()">{{ ValuesStore.variables.visible }}</div>
  </div>
```

**Code**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

function FirstController($scope, ValuesStore) {
  $scope.ValuesStore = ValuesStore;
}

function SecondController($scope, ValuesStore) {
  $scope.ValuesStore = ValuesStore;
}

angular.module("plunker")
  .service("ValuesStore", function() {

    this.variables = {};

    this.variables.visible = true;

    this.toggle = function() {
      console.log(this.variables.visible);
      this.variables.visible = !this.variables.visible;
    }
  });
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/JCUrdPtaokr6kmplBU6c?p=preview)

Comment: @JuanMoreno could you upvote this if it does helped you? Do you like my appoach without watcher?

Comment: I just now received my first 15 points., so yes, I have upvote your answer. Thanks sir :) pankajparkar

Answer (score 3):

In your controller, bind to service directly.

```
function FirstController($scope, ValuesStore) {
    $scope.ValuesStore = ValuesStore;
}

function SecondController($scope, ValuesStore) {
    $scope.ValuesStore = ValuesStore;
}
```

Then in your view, you can access the property by

```
{{ ValuesStore.visible }}
```

Once you trigger `ValuesStore.Toggle()`, they can be updated automatically.

But just like @devqon said, maybe you don't want to involve the whole service in your controller, `$watch` can help you out.

In your first controller, watch `visible`

```
$scope.visible = ValuesStore.visible;

$scope.$watch('visible', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
        ValueStore.visible = newValue;
    }
});
```

In your second controller, keep an eye on `ValuesStore.visible`

```
$scope.visible = ValuesStore.visible;

$scope.$watch(ValueStore.visible, function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
        ValueStore.visible = newValue;
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think you want the whole service in your view. That could be considered bad practice

Comment: @devqon It's an easy to handle data sharing together with bindings, but you are right, sometimes we don't want the whole service. `$watch` is another option, see my update.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
    return ValuesStore.visible;
}, function (newValue) {
    $scope.visible = newValue
});
```

Taken from this example: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/RA2j7/2/